# Problem involving the bivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

> If $X$ and $Y$ have a bivariate normal distribution with $\mu(x)=\mu(y)=0$, $\rho=0$, $\sigma(x)=\sigma(y)=10$. Find the following:
>
> A) The probability of getting a point $(x,y)$ inside the circle $x^2+y^2=25$.
>
> B) The value of $c$ for which the probability of getting a point inside a square with side of length $c$ centered at the origin is $0.49$.

Already found A, need help with B please!

Comment: I realize that a lot of the notation you're using might be standard, but it's still helpful for you, since it might create more potential answerers, to explain it. For example, what is $\rho$?

Comment: That is your correlation, so in this case, correlation is 0